# Null Pointer Exception when trying to set a value

Tags: java, for-loop, nullpointerexception

So pretty much I'm making an array of obvjects called `Spots` which symbolise the different faces of a dice.

It takes user input (manually set to three for this example), and then creates that make `Spots` and rolls a random number from 1 to 6.

However when I go to use the `rollAgain()` method on the aleady created array of `Spots` I get a null pointer even though I am using the same variable length in both for loops (the one that creates and one that rolls the spots).

My code

Global Variables

```
private Spots[] spots;

private int x = 3;
```

Contructor

```
  public Director(JFrame window, String args[]) {
    JMenuBar menus = new JMenuBar();
    window.setJMenuBar(menus);
    menus.add(makeFileMenu());

    window.getContentPane().add(makePanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
    window.getContentPane().add(makeSpots(x), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    rollAgain();
}
```

rollAgain() method

```
public void rollAgain() {
    int v = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        spots[i].setValue(v);
    }
}
```

makeSpots() method

```
private JComponent makeSpots(int x) {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Dice"));

    Spots[] spots = new Spots[x];

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {

        spots[i] = new Spots(200, 200);
        spots[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        p.add(spots[i]);
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Is it too much to ask if I can see the exception stack trace?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel it is not a duplicate.

Comment: `spots` is local to the method, not the instance.

Comment: @MatiCicero yep, the error should be obvious from the code given

Comment: @Ordous What if the exception is thrown inside setValue(v), because he is doing some inner logic with v?.   I know this isn't the case, but we can't know for certain

Comment: @MatiCicero fair enough, with slightly more code and more complex logic it would be a necessity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting a local variable

```
Spots[] spots = new Spots[x];
```

This doesn't change the field (which happens to have the same name)

```
private Spots[] spots;
```

The simplest solution is to not have a local variable

```
this.spots = new Spots[x];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate a new Spots array in your constructor.

```
this.spots = new Spots[x];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spots[i].setValue(v);
```

Judging from this line, my guess is that the `Spot` object in the array in null.

The error is in your `makeSpots()` method. You don't update the value of the field `x`, but use a local variable. Add `this.x = x` at the beginning of the method.

Answer (score 0):

In your `makeSpots()` method, you are creating a new Spots object called spots:

```
Spots[] spots = new Spots[x];
```

This effectively hides your private member variable spots from the method. Instead, do this in your makeSpots() method:

```
spots = new Spots[x];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a global 'spots' array and then in the makeSpots() you create the spots with a local variable also named 'spots'. Just substitute

```
Spots[] spots = new Spots[x];
```

by

```
spots = new Spots[x];
```

so the global variable gets a value.